# Trying to find a drop down menu option by passing in a String

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling to locate a drop down menu item by passing in a String.

String of 'Email'

```
public class Email
{
    public static void Select()
    {
        MenuSelector.SelectOption("Email");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to concatenate the string in-order to find the required option?

```
public static void SelectOption(string option)
{
   Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".form-control>option" + option)).Click();
}
```

Dropdown menu

```
<select class="form-control" name="searchType">
    <option>JobTitle</option>
    <option>Name</option>
    <option>Recruiter</option>
    <option>Reference</option>
    <option>Email</option>
    <option>PhoneNumber</option>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way - [`SelectElement` class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm) and [`SelectByText()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement_SelectByText.htm) method:

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Name("searchType")));
selectElement.SelectByText("PhoneNumber");
```

Comment: Thank you, will give that a try

Comment: For the sake of completeness, the answer should probably contain information about how finding via CSS selectors cannot match on the text of an element, which addresses the _actual_ question initially asked.